# SOLR Search results with associated file

Tags: solr, solr4

I am using solr search (solr 4.X), everything working as expected, I got the requirement that I need to show the associated file also along with the search results.

I am getting the search results but not the files. How do I get, at least I am expecting file name along with the search results.

Thanks for the help. Please help me

Comment: Please show us your schema and tell us a more about how the files are index and queried. Otherwise it is difficult to help you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reply! The schema is exactly example schema. I indexed files using post.jar. I queried solr thru solrj client. I got the results what I want, but I want the associated file also along with the result. ex : I am searching keyword called 'solr' got the results with all fields, not the file name. I am expecting the file name as solr.xml or anythong way. Please help me. Thakns

Comment: If you are not indexing the filename, than this information is not solr and you can't get it back. If you need the filename in your result set, you need to index and store it.

Comment: Thanks. Ic, for instance if I am indexing pdf file how do I add filename as part of index?   In case of xml files, yes I will add filename also as part of my content. Could please suggest me on this.

Comment: post.jar is only for the examples. You will need to generate either the xml files with your own program or use a library like solrj

Comment: I agree,  if you do not mind, can you let me know the steps to get filename from solr> Thanks

Comment: sorry, I have my own xml files for index and even schema.xml also. In my schema.xml I have a field name 'filename' with attributes index=true and strored=true. Is solr expects any thing from my xml file. Like filename or something..I thought solr will automatically detect filename??? Is it..I think I am missting some thing which is key??? Thanks for all your hlep till now.

Answer (score 0):

Solr is a generic enterprise search server. It does not know anything about files or where the data it indexes comes from. You will have do do this on your own.

The Schema (schema.xml) defines what fields get indexed. When you design your schema, you have to make decisions on what is stored and in what way.

If you want the filenames back, you will have to manually add them to your index, by first providing a field in your schema and than by filling that field every time you add something to your index.

You probably do not want to tokenizer your filename, unless you want to search on it, too. If your filename includes a full path, it can be considered unique and you could use it as your id, too.

If you add it via xml, all you need is a new field in your doc list, e.g.

```
  <doc>
      ...
      <field name="filename">/some/path/basename.extension</field>
      ...
  </doc>
```

If you are using solrj, it will look something like this:

```
    HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(host);
    SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
    doc.addField("filename", document.getFilename());
    Collection<SolrInputDocument> docs = new ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>();
    docs.add(doc);
    server.add(docs);
```

Comment: Phisch, Thanks a lot for the response, I got it. One more thing, I understand in case of xml files. The same thing how can I achieve for pdf files?

Comment: You will need to extract the data you are looking for from the PDF and send it to solr (in form of Strings). Apache Tika does the extraction. There are also DataImportHandlers that can handle pdf files, but with limitatins.